# Tidying up the "open with" list for .html files with LibreOffice installed

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, libreoffice

I have LibreOffice installed, with Windows Explorer Extension feature enabled during installation. I don't want to disable that feature, because it has some other benefits.

In the **open with** context menu for .html files, I have two LibreOffice items, both I definitely do not need. I thought that I would be able to get rid of them through registry edits on:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.html\OpenWithList
```

Unfortunately, that list does not have anything related. Why does Windows Explorer let LibreOffice be in that list? Where else are those lists managed in Windows?

Screenshot of evidence:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than `OpenWithList` key, there are some additional registry locations from there the Open with list is generated. `OpenWithProgIDs` is another one. Check:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.html\OpenWithProgIDs
```

and

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.html\OpenWithProgids
```

See list of `Open with` registry keys here: [How to Remove Unwanted "Open with" menu Items in Windows](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/remove-unwanted-entries-open-with-menu-windows/)